# specific price access in prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I'm on prestashop 1.6

When I use this code in my product.tpl file there's no problem, and everything works correctly:

```
{if  $product->specificPrice.from_quantity==0} <img src="http://url/finish.png" >{/if}
```

But the same code in the file, homefeatured.tpl gets an answer wrong
I even changed the code to the following, but I still did not resolve the problem

```
{if  $product.specificPrice.from_quantity==0} <img src="http://url/finish.png" >{/if}
```

or

```
{if  $product.specific_price.from_quantity==0} <img src="http://url/finish.png" >{/if}
```

Please help me, experts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look what actualy is asignet to homefeatured.tpl
It's an array of data what you get from 
`Category->getProducts();`
When you check what is returned you can see, that it returns an array that has a key **[specific_prices]** that contains a key **[from_quantity]**.