# Prestashop 1.6 - Display product's default price and specific price at same time

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

My Prestashop version is 1.6.0.9

Our requirement is to show Product base price and specific price at same time.

The **base price of the product** is **10 Euro**.

The **specific price** is set to **20 Euro** for **visitors group**.

Now the requirement is to show both prices for the all the customers. 
My question is how to get specific price data of visitors group for logged in users?

By referring to this link : [specific price access in prestashop 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955840/specific-price-access-in-prestashop-1-6)

Specific price can be accessed by :

```
$product->specificPrice
```

I displayed the price object and the specific price array is blank for the logged in user.

Any reference will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who needs to get the `specificPrice` (or any price) of a product, you can use the static method `getPriceStatic()` from the `Product` class ( `your_ps_install_dir/classes/Product.php` ) :

```
Product::getPriceStatic(
    $id_product, 
    $usetax = true, 
    $id_product_attribute = null, 
    $decimals = 6, 
    $divisor = null, 
    $only_reduc = false, 
    $usereduc = true, 
    $quantity = 1, 
    $force_associated_tax = false, 
    $id_customer = null, 
    $id_cart = null, 
    $id_address = null, 
    &$specific_price_output = null, 
    $with_ecotax = true, 
    $use_group_reduction = true, 
    Context $context = null, 
    $use_customer_price = true 
);
```

Hope that can help.